# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Pt1

Tags: calculus

How can you solve this problem?

Use part $1$ of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative of the function $$h(x) = \int_1^{\large e^{x}} 8 \ln(t) dt$$

I got $8x$ as the answer.

The $\ln$ gets cancelled with the $e^x$, but I still get the wrong answer.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax references.

Comment: Why did this question get so many downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Use chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{\exp(x)}8 \ln (t) dt = 8\ln(\exp(x)) \frac{d}{dx}\exp(x) = 8x\exp(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$H(x)=\int^{e^x}_{1}8\ln(t)dt$$
$$H'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int^{e^x}_{1}8\ln(t)dt=8\frac{d}{dx}\int^{e^x}_{1}\ln(t)dt$$

If we have $\int^{u(x)}_{1}f(t)dt$, then the deriviative is equal to $f(u(x))\times (u(x))'$.

So we have that $$8\frac{d}{dx}\int^{e^x}_{1}\ln(t)dt=8\ln(e^x)\times(e^x)'=8\ln(e^x)\times(e^x)=8xe^x$$

Recall that $\ln(e^x)=x\ln(e)=x(1)=x$